# Using CSS custom properties with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-variables

I want to use CSS custom properties within a flexbox to define my `flex-basis`, which can be variable. The following code doesn't work correctly. The variable is computed fine but the `flex-basis` just isn't applied. Is it possible to use custom properties within the `flex` property like this?

```
.row-flex {
    --flex-basis: 30%;

    display: flex;
}

.row-flex >:first-child {
     flex-basis: 0 0 var(--flex-basis);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

custom properties is working fine with flexbox but the problem is with your last css line.

you should use as:

```
.row-flex >:first-child {
     flex: 0 0 var(--flex-basis);
}
```

or

```
.row-flex >:first-child {
     flex-basis: var(--flex-basis);
}
```

`flex-basis` takes only one argument which is the value. while flex takes 3 args: (flex-grow - flex-shrink - flex-basis)

see this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/c90vestg/1/)